# Android/Arduino bluetooth communication

Tags: java, android, arduino

Link successfully established and able to send data.

Android is sending SeekBar data when ever we change it.

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    if(seekBar.getId() == R.id.seekBar)
    {
        speed.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        String outputData = String.valueOf(progress);
        streams.write(outputData.getBytes());
    }
}
```

`streams.write()` writes data to the `OutputStream` of the `Socket`.

Problem is with the format of data.If I Send '25' arduino is receiving '2','5' when I do `Serial.read()`.

What is the format of data, when `outputData` is converted into bytes? Is everything terminated by `\0`?

I need to retrieve the whole number instead of single digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the arduinoboard seems to read the RX-Stream byte by byte. If you send "25" it transmits the ascii byte for the character'2' (which is 0x32 / decimal 50) and then the ascii representation for the character '5' (which is 0x35 / decimal 53).
The arduino interprets these numbers as characters. So if the number you want to transmit is lower than 256 you can do:
On Android:

```
if(seekBar.getId() == R.id.seekBar)
    {
        speed.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        if(progress<256)
            streams.write((byte)progress);
    }
```

To make sure the Arduino interprets it right, use the received character as a short and not as a character.

Hope this helps

Comment: Erhm, `int currVal = valueOf(progress);` would do exactly what? Which `valueOf` are you referring to? And what do you want to achieve by sending an un-initialized array sized `currVal` over the wire?

Comment: I am SO sorry. I must have been really tired yesterday ^^ sorry for that crap. I edited the code that it is right. Sorry again o.O

Answer (score 1):

For the sender side, the getBytes() does not return a C string with a null terminator.  In Java, arrays contain information about their length.  So the byte[] contains its length; it is not like a C char[] which uses a null to indicate the end of the array.  If you want to translate the outbound data you need to add the terminator yourself:

```
String outputData = String.valueOf(progress);
streams.write(outputData.getBytes());
streams.write('\0');
```

Note that the getBytes() can completely break down if the the character set default encoding changes on the Android side.  On a different Android device, the getBytes() could return unicode character set encoding, which the Arduino would not be able to decode.

Comment: unicode characters won't be a problem if I send only some standard characters like '0-9', ',' , '\0'. The ascii values for these characters would be same at both android and arduino sides right?

Comment: Nope.  Without an explicit encoding, the getBytes() will use the JVM default character encoding.  That default is platform dependent, so your program may be at risk.  To see this, if you run your JVM with the argument -Dfile.encoding="UTF-16", the getBytes() will not return one byte for each character.

Comment: Yeah got it.But here is the problem now.I have finished my app and I don't understand why I'm getting correct results.If I send "10" from android,I guess the data is being as '1' and later '0'.I think each character is of 2 bytes at android end.But I'm using readBytesUntil() function at arduino side.Technically this should print out wrong results at arduino side.But I'm getting correct values.What's happening?

Comment: This may clear up: internally a Java String is always using 2 bytes of memory per character.  Despite the name, String getBytes() does not give you the underlying memory--it gives you a byte[] array coded in the platform default encoding.  If you pass a encoding name as a parameter to getBytes(), it will return a byte[] array encoded as you specify.  For your platform, the default encoding is UTF-8, so getBytes() is giving you one ASCII byte for every character in the String.  does that clear up?

Answer (score 0):

You have an int, convert it to a string and send the string:

```
 String outputData = String.valueOf(progress);
 streams.write(outputData.getBytes());
```

How about just [sending the int](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#write%28int%29):

```
streams.write( progress );
```

On the Arduino side [`Serial.read()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/read) reads a byte at a time, so (assuming big endianess on the wire) you could do

```
int incomingByte = Serial.read();
incomingByte <<= 8;
incomingByte |= Serial.read();
```

Cheers,