# Arduino - Android Communication SeekBar Value

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, seekbar, dataformat

I have an app which communicate Arduino via Bluetooth. I want to change speeds of DC motors using seekbar, there is not any problem about communication, the problem is format I think, because while I am moving the bar, I check the results from Arduino Serial Port screen, and see different symbols like ! " # ' $ ) ( * < : and some of them are normal character like A,B,C... I need only integer between 0-255 Found and tried [these answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893860/android-arduino-bluetooth-communication) but it did not help

This is Android part

```
seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        int speed= 0;

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            speed = progress;

            if(btSocket!=null){
                try {
                    btSocket.getOutputStream().write(speed);
                } catch (IOException e){
                    msg("Error");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

This is Arduino Part

```
int pwm_a = 3;  
int pwm_b = 11; 
int dir_a = 12; 
int dir_b = 13;  
char incomingByte; //incoming data for directions  
int speed; // incoming data for speed

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pwm_a, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pwm_b, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dir_a, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dir_b, OUTPUT);

  analogWrite(pwm_a, 0);  
  analogWrite(pwm_b, 0);

}

void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available() > 0){ //if the data came
incomingByte = Serial.read();
speed = Serial.read();


if (incomingByte == 'F'){
forward();}
  else if (incomingByte == 'B'){
back();}
if (incomingByte == 'R'){
right();}
if (incomingByte == 'L'){
left();}
if (incomingByte == 'S'){
stop();
    }
  }
}

void forward() 
{ digitalWrite(dir_a, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dir_b, HIGH);  
  analogWrite(pwm_a, speed);    
  analogWrite(pwm_b, speed);
}

void back() 
{ digitalWrite(dir_a, LOW); 
  digitalWrite(dir_b, LOW);  
  analogWrite(pwm_a, speed);    
  analogWrite(pwm_b, speed);
}
void right() 
{ digitalWrite(dir_a, LOW); 
  digitalWrite(dir_b, HIGH);  
  analogWrite(pwm_a, speed);    
  analogWrite(pwm_b, speed);
}

void left() 
{ digitalWrite(dir_a, HIGH); 
  digitalWrite(dir_b, LOW);  
  analogWrite(pwm_a, speed);    
  analogWrite(pwm_b, speed);
}
void stop() 
{ digitalWrite(dir_a, LOW); 
  digitalWrite(dir_b, LOW);  
  analogWrite(pwm_a, 0);    
  analogWrite(pwm_b, 0);
}
```

Comment: the communication is done in bytes I suppose..

Comment: Also are you using similar encoding types at both the ends?

Comment: Yes, normally while sending direction I use btSocket.getOutputStream().write("F".getBytes()); similarly I tried btSocket.getOutputStream().write((byte)speed); but nothing changed. Also tried  String outputData = String.valueOf(speed);
 btSocket.getOutputStream.write(speed.getBytes());

Comment: In all this cases it is printing garbage values? and what is the encoding type you are using?

Comment: UTF-8. Yes, generally garbage, only integers I saw 1-9, and also some letters that I mentioned above

Comment: Are you using some library for sending and receiving data?

Comment: Not a special thing. I am using regular android bluetooth libraries

Comment: You can achieve this by using software based serial library at the arduino's end.. here's a tutorial link - https://bellcode.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/android-and-arduino-bluetooth-communication/

Comment: check out this tutorial too - http://solderer.tv/data-transfer-between-android-and-arduino-via-bluetooth/

Comment: These tutorials do not answer my question. My main problem is format of seekbars values. I send integers but Arduino dont get them like integer.

Comment: You have to send the data in byte array.. sending integer wont work as the arduino reading the data in bytes

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a class to make a bluetooth connection between Android and Arduino. My code is on github:

**https://github.com/omaflak/Bluetooth-Android**

I also wrote a tutorial on my blog, you may want to take a look at it, there is the code for Arduino and everything:

**https://causeyourestuck.io/2015/12/14/communication-between-android-and-hc-06-module/**

Good luck!